# How to style multi list codename one?

Tags: java, android, cross-platform, codenameone

I am having a bit of a snag with multi list. I need to fill the multi list with some color. I managed to fill it but still there are some kind of a border that I can't cover. I tried `margin 0, padding 0` but the border still exists. I even put a border on the lines and the list, still the same result. I tried putting background for everything. The only choice left is to switch the white borders to black

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's coming from the `MultiButton` UIID which you probably won't want to customize. You can workaround this by using:

```
list.getSelectedButton().setUIID("Container");
list.getUnselectedButton().setUIID("Container");
```

I suggest avoiding lists entirely [as discussed in this post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html).